# select checkboxes inside datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a datagrid bound to a database table. In that datagrid, I have checkbox coulmn which is not bound to the database table. I have a button in the form to select all the checkboxes. How can I check all the checkboxes using C# code.

Also, how can I check through code if the checkbox in a row is selected

Thanks

Comment: I am going to be "that guy" and say "you should be using an ItemsControl instead of a DataGrid because DataGrids introduce more trouble than they are worth" but that's quite controversial.

Comment: You could simply add a new column to your DataTable, like IsChecked, and bind `IsChecked` of the `CheckBox` to that. Otherwise, the `DataGrid` uses virtualization by default so if you have more then maybe 20 rows, the odds are you ain't gonna find all the CheckBoxes even if you search the Visual Tree because they're not currently generated. But if you wanna try that, look inte VisualTreeHelper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already search Stack for your answer?

[c# code for select all checkbox in wpf datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756033/c-code-for-select-all-checkbox-in-wpf-datagrid)

['Check All' checkbox for a WPF DataGrid, where the checkboxes already have a source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281563/check-all-checkbox-for-a-wpf-datagrid-where-the-checkboxes-already-have-a-sour)

Are these close?